# Find exact and similar company name in String

Tags: php, preg-match

Hi I trying now to check if some company is in one string. I am working with LinkedIn and because my source of companies is not like the LinkedIn one I need in PHP something like similar search.

Example:

If I become from my source the names:

```
array("Company", "Company Inc.", "Company Inc");
```

All 3 Strings should match (true) with the companies

```
"Company" and "Company Inc." .
```

because some of my friends has written as company "Company" and other "Company Inc."

The solution should be make possible, that any of the source companies found the both from LinkedIn.

Thanks
Nik

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php similar_text is simple PHP function which may help you ..

Comment: Your example is confusing: Is company the Name of the Company? or do you want a name with or without 'company'? company and inc are common siffixes so .... WHAT?

Comment: Look Oliver. If I send the String "Google" I need to find all contacts which have in their LinkedIn profile "Google" or "Google Inc.". The same: if I send the string "Google Inc." I want to become all friends with "Google" and "Google Inc." as company. Ok?

Answer (score 0):

PHP bring a number of functions for such fuzzy string comparision. Take a look at these:

- [soundex()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.soundex.php)
- [levenshtein()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.soundex.php)
- [metaphone()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.metaphone.php)
- [similar-text()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.similar-text.php)